# Access the datas in redux-persist (react native)

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-persist

I am a newbie in react-redux. I am trying a Todo app using redux. Here I need to store the data and show them as soon as the app opens, for which redux-persist is used. And it works fine. The one where I am stuck is in action. I have initialized id = 0 here. Hence every time app opens, it stores the data from id = 0 and then increments. How can I refer to the last id stored from persist and use it when the new data is added?

App.js

```
export const persistor = persistStore(store);

class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={<ActivityIndicator />} persistor={persistor}>
          <ToDoApp />
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

store

```
const persistConfig = {
     key: 'root',
     storage,
     stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2 
};

const pReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export default (store = createStore(pReducer));
```

action

```
import { ADD_TODO, TOGGLE_TODO } from './actionTypes';

let nextId = 0; // how to initialize nextId as the last id from persisted data?
export const addToDoo = text => ({
  type: ADD_TODO,
  id: nextId++,
  text
});

export const toggleTodo = id => ({
  type: TOGGLE_TODO,
  id
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used `redux-persist` so far, I'm using [this technique](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-persisting-the-state-to-the-local-storage) but that is off-topic, your problem is only related to `redux`.

It's not the job of an action creator to assign an id to a new todo, it's the reducer's job. Your action could look like:

```
const addTodo = text => ({
  type: ADD_TODO,
  text,
})
```

That's in the reducer that must reside `nextId`. At startup (or page reload), it will be 0 or the value stored in localStorage. There it will increment every time an ADD_TODO action comes up:

```
const initialState = {
  nextId: 0,
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      //...
    case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
      //...
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

I see `redux-persist` does all the magic of serializing the state to storage (localStorage for browser and AsyncStorage for React-Native) and retrieving it at startup. For reference,  that is what I would do for a pure React App (the old way with localStorage):

- In the root `index.js`, after the createStore, I to get the value from storage: `const nextIdFromLS = storage.getItem("nextId")`
- if this value exists, I fire an action to set this nextId value `store.dispatch(setNextId(nextIdFromLS))`
- the action `SET_NEXT_ID` makes the reducer update the state with the nextId from localStorage
- next time a todo is added, inside the `case "ADD_TODO":`, I would store the new todo as expected but I would also run `localStorage.setItem("nextId", this.state.nextId++)` so that we have the value stored and we can refresh the page

Comment: There's no localStorage in react native. I think AsyncStorage is equivalent to it but I'm told that redux-persist is easier and better.

Comment: I missed that react-native detail, I updated my answer ;) I hope my answer enlightened the principle that data must reside in state and be kept there, that's what make redux so cool. By residing data, I mean data that is kept between two action rounds. Actions will bring new data, but it's flowing data, moving data. For example, Action2 can't access action1's raw data BUT can access the modified state after action1 occurred.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't get you. I am just starting redux. Can you please have a look at https://snack.expo.io/@codebyte99/reduxexample

Comment: If you can have a look here: https://snack.expo.io/ByQ_v5k9X. I removed the `redux-persist` layer for now as your problem is related to `redux`. The idea is that you state shape was `[<todos>]`, I changed it for `{ nextId: <int>, list: <todos> }`. Now I can increment that nextId every time ADD_TODO arrives and use that id for the new todo.

Comment: Sorry there is a small typo above the new state shape is `{ nextId: <int>, list: [<todos>] }`. Note that I initialize the state in the reducer with `{ nextId: 0, list: [] }`.

Comment: Thankyou so so much